# Updated API related to DocumentHelper.AddAttachment() method in Kentico10

Tags: kentico

As DocumentHelper.AddAttachment() method is changed in Kentico 10 I need the alternate approach to my below code ::

```
 public void InsertAttachment(string url, SKUTreeNode productDoc)
    {
        string file = DownloadImage(url);

        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(file))
        {
            Bitmap bmp = (Bitmap)System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(Server.MapPath(file), true);
            AttachmentInfo attachment = DocumentHelper.AddAttachment(productDoc, "ProductImage", file, tree);
            attachment.AttachmentImageHeight = getRelativeHeight(bmp);
            attachment.AttachmentImageWidth = 300;
            attachment.AttachmentIsUnsorted = true;
            AttachmentInfoProvider.SetAttachmentInfo(attachment);
            productDoc.Update();
        }
    }
```

Based on suggestion from [this link](https://devnet.kentico.com/documentation/api-changes/kentico-10/23737)
If I replace AttachmentInfo with DocumentAttach return type and remove the last argument in AddAttachment method then what about the SetAttachmentInfo method and how will I relate the added attachment with the tree ? What code should replace my this line of code
AttachmentInfoProvider.SetAttachmentInfo(attachment);

Answer (score 1):

[Here are the examples here](https://docs.kentico.com/api10/content-management/attachments)

```
 // Saves the modified attachment into the database
 attachment.Update();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can update the attachment after you add it to the document:

```
 attachment.AttachmentImageHeight = getRelativeHeight(bmp);
 attachment.AttachmentImageWidth = 300;
 attachment.AttachmentIsUnsorted = true;
 DocumentHelper.UpdateAttachment(Node, attachment);
```